# Ubuntu Server 16.04 error 60: SSL certificate problem

Tags: apache, ssl, curl, ubuntu-16.04

Ubuntu server 16.04 PHP7.4 Apache2 running wordpress Geotrust SHA256 certificate

I have started  getting the following error

cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I have read through and tried most solutions on the many questions on here, but to no avail

The latest 2 i have tried is adding to php.ini the following 2 lines and restarted Apache and rebooted after each one to see if it solves the issue. But it does not

After downloading a fresh copy of cacert.pem The first one i tried was

```
curl.cainfo = "/path/to/cacert.pem"
```

Then i tried

```
openssl.cafile = "/path/to/cacert.pem"
```

But i still get the same error

Any assistance greatly appreciated.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to be a server problem ("unable to get local issuer certificate" often is):

Even when using a CA bundle to verify a server cert, you might still experience problems if your CA store does not contain the certificates for the *intermediates* if the server doesn't provide them.

The TLS protocol mandates that the intermediate certificates are sent in the handshake, but as browsers have ways to survive or work around such omissions, missing intermediates in TLS handshakes still happen that browser-users won't notice.

Browsers work around this problem in two ways: they cache intermediate certificates from previous transfers and some implement the TLS "AIA" extension that lets the client explicitly download such cerfificates on demand.

To figure out for sure if this is your problem, use a TLS test service like perhaps this one: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/